# setting css style for s property in struts 2

Tags: css, struts2

I have a property field like

```
<s:property value="%{dp.pL[#status.index].val}" escape="false" />
```

If the value of the property is greater than 1, I want to set the text in red color if it is not it should be normal.

I tried the below code

```
<td width="60px" class="class1">
    <s:if test="%{dp.pL[#status.index].val}" escape="false" ">
    <span class = "red">
    <s:property value="%{dp.pL[#status.index].val}" escape="false" />
    </span>
    </s:if>

//else just the property value
</td>
```

But this is failing 
Any leads ?

Comment: You can set the class based on condition.

Comment: @Roman I tried that and I have posted even the code. I guess I am making some syntax error or something that it is failing.